# Complexity of std::find_end as Big-O

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity-theory

How can I represent the complexity of `std::find_end` algorithm as Big-O notation?

The complexity of `std::find_end` is defined as follows:

> At most `(last2 - first2) * (last1 - first1 - (last2 - first2) + 1)`
>   applications of the corresponding predicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be `O(M*(N-M))`, where `N` is the number of elements in the sequence 1, and `M` is the number of elements in the sequence 2.